# Dividir en una consulta entre dos funciones de agregado

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una tabla que registra bastantes datos de los pasajeros del Titanic. Estoy haciendo una serie de ejercicios con ellos, pero me he quedado estancado a la hora de calcular el porcentaje de supervivientes. Con funciones agregadas puedo calcular, en dos consultas diferentes, el total de pasajeros y el total de supervivientes (es una columna de tipo INT donde 0 es que no sobrevivió y 1 que sí sobrevivió). El problema viene al juntar ambas consultas en una sola (con el operador de dividir "/") para logar un resultado con el porcentaje total de supervivientes.

Las he intentado unir en una sola consulta múltiples veces y todo son errores.

¿Alguna pista de cómo se debería de hacer? Dejos las dos consultas que tengo por separado:

```
select count(survived) from titanic where survived = 1;

/*Resultado = 500*/

select count(*)from titanic;

/* Resultado = 1310 */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  round(100.0 * sum(survived) / count(*), 2) AS "porcentaje_sobrevivientes"
FROM
  titanic;
```

En esta consulta lo que hacemos es:

1. Sumamos el numero de sobrevivientes usando al función `sum`.
2. mediante `count(*)` contamos le total de pasajeros
3. Dividimos el numero de sobrevivientes entre el total de pasajeros para obtener una proporción
4. Multiplicamos el anterior resultado por 100 esto debido a que es la forma de realizar una interpolacion lineal directa
5. Redondeamos a dos decimales mediante la funcion round

Comment: He hecho lo que dices (quitando algún elemento para simplificar y curiosamente lo calcula correctamente).

El problema es que no entiendo por qué, porque la columna "survived" solo contiene un 0 si la persona murió y un 1 si la persona vivió pero no hemos indicado esa condición en la consulta...

Comment: estamos sumando todos, si le sumas cero a cualquier cosa te dará cero. a esto se le conoce como neutro aditivo. Asi que los obviamos y sumamos todos los 1 de survived.

Comment: Ah vale, claro, ya entiendo al ser sumatorio solo suma los que son  = 1. Pero entonces esta forma, aunque funcione para este caso concreto, no sería la mejor forma de hacerlo, ¿no? Si muerto fuese = 1 y vivo = 2 en la tabla, ya no funcionaría...

Comment: exacto, no funcionaria si hubiera zombies, es decir personas que hubieran muerto mas de una vez. Si el 1 y el dos no fueral el numero de muertes sino valores de enumeracion podrias usar un case como en la consulta de lobos

Comment: Entiendo, pero los siguientes pasos necesito meterle alguna condición (por ejemplo, supervivientes que sean solamente mujeres) y sigue sin haber forma. Al meter el where sex ='female' da error y no entiendo por qué...

Comment: para los siguientes pasos intenta llegar a ellos y si no funciona haz otra pregunta